# How do I listen to Pervasive Database Event from .NET

Tags: database, events, listener, pervasive

I would like to listen to changes happening on a pervasive database table using .Net...

For example:

I have a Client table with a column for Phone Number.

I would like to know how to listen for changes to the Phone Number column for any record on the Client Table.

I would prefer to use .Net, but I do not mind using something else if need be.

My end goal is to catch this information and send it to another server via an HTTP POST.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to hook into the Pervasive engine directly without using [Data Exchange](http://pervasivedb.com/dataexchange/Pages/Default.aspx) (replication) or [Audit Master](http://pervasivedb.com/auditmaster/Pages/Default.aspx) (auditing) from Pervasive.

If, and it's a big if, your application uses only the SQL engine you might be able to create a Trigger that writes a record to another table and then in a .NET application look for records in that table and do with it as you want.

Audit Master would probably do something similar to what you want.  It can be configured to send an email or run a program when a tracked operation occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will check out Data Exchange and Audit Master.  Much appreciated.